# Passing javascript Date object to C# WebBrowser control using window.external

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, webbrowser-control, com-interop

I am able to call C# methods of `WebBrowser.ObjectForScripting` with javascript `window.external` from `WebBrowser` WinForms control and pass `string`, `int`, `bool` etc. However I don't know how to pass javascript `Date` object and somehow convert/marshal it to .NET `DateTime` class.

Obviously, I could pass a `string` and parse it, but this is really not the point. I'm just curious how could I do it with javascript `Date` and .NET `DateTime`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working. I don't know why, but I am unable to use it with `dynamic`. Here is the solution:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Foo
{
    public void Bar(object o)
    {
        var dateTime = (DateTime)o.GetType().InvokeMember("getVarDate", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, o, null);
        Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of the fact that [dates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) in Javascript are expressed as the number of milliseconds elapsed since the [UNIX epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch) (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC). Use the [valueOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) method to obtain that value from a `Date` object :

```
var millisecondsSinceEpoch = yourDate.valueOf();
```

If you can marshal that value to C# as a `double`, you can create the appropriate `DateTime` object using its constructor and the [AddMilliseconds()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmilliseconds.aspx) method:

```
DateTime yourDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
    .AddMilliseconds(millisecondsSinceEpoch);
```

Comment: I could do that, but I am looking only for solution for how to read javascript `Date` object in C#. I'm not even sure if that's possible, but if it's not, that's ok. But I'm hoping that there is some way to do that.

Comment: There are no "Javascript Date objects" in C#

Comment: As far as I understand, when I pass `Date` object to C# it's marshaled using COM, so I suppose it's possible to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I found better solution for my project.

in javascript:

```
var date = new Date();
myComObject.DoSomething(date.getVarDate());
```

in C#

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Foo
{
    public void Bar(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course it's possible, but I was wondering how to do that without calling `getVarDate` in javascript.